# Visa Change in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, resident-permit

If a person visiting Germany from Pakistan marries a Dutch Girl in Germany, can he change the visa without leaving or will he have to leave?

Secondly what will be the process for Applying for a residence permit?

Comment: A person visiting Germany on a tourist visa won’t be even able to marry a Dutch girl. So the question about changing the visa doesn’t make any sense. But yes, changing a tourist visa in Germany is not possible.

Comment: @ExPatriot do you have a reference to support that?  Also, the question does not explicitly mention a visitor's visa.  If there is a special visa required, perhaps the Pakistani has it.

Comment: @ExPatriot While I see a lot of paperwork problems making it inconvenient and tedious, I cannot remember being asked for a visa along the whole process. Do you have any links what type of visa would be required for an EU and a non-EU national to get married in Germany?

Comment: @nvoigt Well, I was't quite right. It is possible to marry in Germany with a visitor's visa but it's impossible to change that visa into a long term visa. There is a special marriage visa for those who want to marry in Germany and stay in the country after that.

Comment: @ExPatriot EU freedom of movement rights take priority over domestic immigration law, however, so the prohibition on changing the visitor visa into a long term visa should not apply in this case.  More precisely, after the marriage, the non-EU spouse no longer needs a long-term visa nor a residence permit, so the prohibited change is no longer necessary.

Comment: @phoog but not over marriage law. They must get married first. Very likely the Dutch Girl must be a registered resident to get married at all. First things first. Without marriage he is not a spouse of an EU citizen.

Comment: @MarkJohnson actually EU free movement also applies to unmarried "partners in a durable relationship," but the definition of that term is left to national law, and it is not clear how Germany applies that provision of the directive. Ex Patriot says in an earlier comment that one can marry in Germany with a visitor visa, which suggests that a Dutch citizen not registered in Germany can also get married there. Alternatively, she can register there easily, or the couple can marry in NL or elsewhere. My point is that *once they are married,* the prohibition on changing status no longer applies.

Comment: @phoog yes, but that was not given in the question. ExPatriot information about visitors getting married is false. The best option is getting married in the NL where the girl in known. Also the groom will probably have to provide proof that he is not married (**Ehefähigkeitsbescheinigung**), which the Dutch may also require.

Comment: @MarkJohnson indeed, an official or authoritative reference on the residence requirements for marriage in Germany would be welcome.

Comment: @phoog try §42 Gesetz über die Beurkundung des Personenstandes und die Eheschließung of 1875. Where the responsible Standesamt is state a place of main residence. The following link (in German)  also shows a list of documents needed (which a casual visitor never can fullfil) : https://www.rtl.de/cms/diese-unterlagen-brauchen-sie-fuer-die-standesamtliche-trauung-4111900.html

Comment: @phoog an english list can be seen here as the requirements for registration of a foreign marriage in Germany (indended for Germans outside of Germany ) : https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/naming-law/registrationofmarriage

Answer (score 1):

A non-EU citizen who is the spouse of an EU citizen enjoys freedom of movement under [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/AUTO/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) when present in an EU or Schengen country other than the country of the spouse's citizenship.  So in this scenario, it is not necessary to leave Germany, and no residence permit is required, but rather a residence *card* issued under Article 10 of the directive.  The card may be obtained from the local *Ausländerbehörde.*

Note that it may not be possible to marry in Germany after traveling there with a regular Schengen visa, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: on what visa can a person marry in Germany with a dutch girl and get the residence card issued?

Comment: Secondly if the Dutch Citizen marries the person before and then moves to Germany can she get his residence card issued?

Comment: @SyedKazim I don't know about the visa for getting married.  If nobody addresses that in the next couple of days I'll look it up (I'll be traveling).  If the couple marry while the non-EU spouse is outside the Schengen area, and if the non-EU spouse requires a visa (as do citizens of Pakistan) then the non-EU spouse will need to get a visa (free of charge and subject to only very limited grounds of refusal) before traveling to Germany, where it will be necessary to apply for a residence card at the *Ausländerbehörde.*  In both cases the non-EU spouse must submit the application.

Comment: While Applying for the visa from Pakistan does the EU Spouse has to be in Germany or she can stay in Netherlands while non-EU Spouse apply for a German visa. And what type of visa will the non-EU Spouse apply for?

Comment: @SyedKazim the EU spouse's location at the time of the visa application is not relevant.  She could be in Mozambique or sailing in the Pacific.  The visa is a visa for the family member of a union citizen.

Comment: What type of visa should be applied after which he can apply for residence card?

Comment: @SyedKazim a visa for the family member of a union citizen.  On [this page](https://pakistan.diplo.de/pk-en/service/-/2208622) it says "spouses/children" instead of "family members," but since this question concerns a spouse, the difference is not material.

Comment: After getting this visa i can enter Germany and then apply for a residence card?

Comment: @SyedKazim yes.  Under the free movement directive, it doesn't matter how you enter Germany if you are the spouse of a non-German citizen.  You are entitled to apply for the card if you are in Germany.  But the usual visa to get is the one for EU citizens.  If you already have a valid Schengen visa, you can use that.

Comment: "But the usual visa to get is the one for EU citizens" can u explain this part?

Comment: and with this residence card i can work in Germany?

Comment: After travelling to Germany does the spouse have to be present or move to Germany to apply for residence permit? and how long does the procedure take?

Comment: @SyedKazim the right of residence under the directive includes the right to work. The EU spouse should be present in Germany when the non-EU spouse arrives at passport control.  Alternatively, they can arrive together.  The couple should be residing together in Germany when the application for the residence card is submitted.  I don't know how long the process takes.

Comment: The EU Spouse can travel on the day of arrival of non-EU Spouse and then start living him there or she should move to Germany before his arrival?

Comment: @SyedKazim they can move to Germany on the same day.

Comment: But the usual visa to get is the one for EU citizens" can u explain this part?

Comment: @SyedKazim "But the usual visa to get is the one for EU citizens" is a mistake.  It should say "But the usual visa to get is the one for family members of EU citizens"

Comment: Is there any requirement for the EU citizen when applying for residence card of non-EU spouse such as job or apartment or something?

Comment: @SyedKazim the EU citizen either must have been resident in Germany for less than three months (see Article 6) or must be a worker, self-employed, self-sufficient, or a student (see Article 7).

Comment: So if the EU citizen moves to Germany on the same day as her non-EU Spouse or travels with him to Germany, Then the non-EU Spouse can apply for residence card since the EU citizen will have been resident for less then 3 months as mentioned in article 6 or will she have to fulfill article 7 for him to get his residence card. kindly elaborate

Comment: @SyedKazim As an example, [here are the requirements in Berlin](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324282/en/). It looks like they actually require the non-EU spouse to meet the requirements of Art. 7 and to have registered his or her residence.

Comment: Can u kindly find me the details for Aachen? and as it mentions non-eu spouse to fulfill the requirement for article 7 so does that mean that the non-EU spouse can find and start work even before applying for resident card?

Comment: @SyedKazim I don't know much about how it works in Germany, but basically it's *legal* for the non-EU spouse to work without a residence card, but administratively, practically, it's probably not possible to find an employer who will employ the person without one. In the UK, a "certificate of application" is adequate to prove authorization to work before the card is received; maybe the same is true in Germany. Aachen has [no information online](https://bportal.staedteregion-aachen.de/staedteregion-a-z/-/egov-bis-search/service/15032), just a note to get in touch with the information desk.

Comment: One more scenario I wanted to ask you about. If the NON-EU Spouse travels to Netherlands on visit Visa then both the EU & NON-EU Spouse travel to Germany can the NON-EU Spouse apply for German residence card using the freedom of movement act?